# Clean task does not clean up specified outputs.file

Tags: build, gradle, resource-cleanup

I wrote a build.gradle script to automatically download hazelcast from a given URL. Afterwards the file is unzipped and only the mancenter.war as well as the origin zip file remains in the destination directory. Later on this war file is taken referenced for a jetty run.

Nevertheless, although I defined outputs.file for two of my tasks, the files do not get cleaned up when I execute gradle clean. Thus I'd like to know what I have to do that the downloaded and unzipped files get removed when I execute gradle clean. Here is my script:

Btw., if you have any recommendations how to enhance the script, please don't hesitate to tell me!

```
apply plugin: "application"

dependencies {
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:${jettyVersion}"
    compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:${jettyVersion}"
}

ext {
    distDir = "${projectDir}/dist"

    downloadUrl = "http://download.hazelcast.com/download.jsp?version=hazelcast-${hazelcastVersion}"
    zipFilePath = "${distDir}/hazelcast-${hazelcastVersion}.zip"
    warFilePath = "${distDir}/mancenter-${hazelcastVersion}.war"

    mainClass = "mancenter.MancenterBootstrap"
}

task downloadZip() {
    outputs.file file(zipFilePath)
    logging.setLevel(LogLevel.INFO)
    doLast {
        ant.get(src: downloadUrl, dest: zipFilePath)
    }
}

task extractWar(dependsOn: downloadZip) {
    outputs.file file(warFilePath)
    logging.setLevel(LogLevel.INFO)
    doLast {
        ant.unzip(src: zipFilePath, dest: distDir, overwrite:"true") {
            patternset( ) {
                include( name: '**/mancenter*.war' )
            }
            mapper(type:"flatten")
        }
    }
}

task startMancenter(dependsOn: extractWar, type: JavaExec) {
    main mainClass
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    args warFilePath
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found this [link](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/is_it_possible_to_partial_override_clean_task), which describes how to provide additional locations to delete when the clean task is invoked. Basically you can do sth. like this:

```
clean{
    delete zipFilePath
    delete warFilePath
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, the clean task simply deletes the build directory. You should store all your outputs somewhere under this build directory.

Comment: Good hint, thank you! Will try it. There is now way to specify additional resources to clean though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got confirmation from the source code that the clean task simply deletes the build directory. It assumes that you want to clean everything, and that all the task outputs are somewhere in this build directory.

So, the easiest and best practice is to only store outputs somewhere under the build directory.

Comment: Think you are right with easiest and best practice. Nevertheless I'll go for the approach I stated in the updated question.

Comment: That will delete during the configuration phase, instead of doing it in the execution phase. It should be `clean << { ... }`

Comment: I think configuration phase is the right phase to do it, since you do not really delete the files but just specify them for later deletion. Also gradle devs stated it like this and it worked for me as well.

Comment: My bad, you're right. I missed the fact that the Delete task had a delete() method, that was called here and not the Project.delete() method, which has the same signature but deletes files immediately.

Answer (score 3):

You can add tasks to clean like this:

```
clean.dependsOn(cleanExtractWar)
clean.dependsOn(cleanDownloadZip)
```

cleanTaskName is a virtual task will clear all outputs for TaskName.